# Retrieve Package.xml using python from salesforce org

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce

I am trying to retrieve a Package.xml using Python. All the modules are supporting metadata extraction from objects but not from a Package.xml file.

Is there any package that can help for this cause?

Answer (score 0):

Use Rest API to get the Salesforce data if you are using python.
it will more helpful to you and you can easily work with it 
here is the link how to use rest API in python 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/